# How can I make it so a where clause with a value of 0 makes it not check the where in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ListIds
    @ObjectiveId int,
    @SubjectId int,
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT Question.QuestionUId
    FROM Objective
    WHERE Objective.objectiveId = @ObjectiveId 
    AND   Objective.subjectId = @SubjectId

END;
```

How can I make it so that if the stored procedure @ObjectiveId is 0 then it does not select **based on the objectiveId** from the table. However I want all the time to select on the Subject Id.

Comment: What should it select instead if it is 0?

Comment: Just select based on the SubjectId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Question.QuestionUId
FROM Objective
WHERE (Objective.objectiveId = @ObjectiveId OR @ObjectiveId = 0)  
      AND Objective.subjectId = @SubjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ListIds
    @ObjectiveId int,
    @SubjectId int,
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT Question.QuestionUId
    FROM Objective
    WHERE (ObjectiveId = 0 OR Objective.objectiveId = @ObjectiveId)
       AND Objective.subjectId = @SubjectId

END;
```

Comment: -1 This is not correct since he wants to filter always by `SubjectId`: _"I want all the time to select on the Subject Id"_. You are filtering only if `ObjectiveId <> 0` which is also incorrect since he wants to skip the `ObjectiveId` filter only if the parameter is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ListIds
    @ObjectiveId int,
    @SubjectId int,
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT Question.QuestionUId
    FROM Objective
    WHERE Objective.objectiveId = case when @ObjectiveId = 0 then Objective.objectiveId 
                                        else ObjectiveId  end
    AND   Objective.subjectId = @SubjectId

END;
```

Comment: This won't work when `Objective.objectiveId` is `null`.

Comment: then handle a case for that isnull(c,'')= ''

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ListIds
    @ObjectiveId  INT,
    @SubjectId    INT 
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT  QuestionUId
    FROM    Objective
    WHERE   Objective.subjectId = @SubjectId AND 
            (ISNULL(@ObjectiveId,0) = 0 OR Objective.objectiveId = @ObjectiveId) 

END;
```